# Can GDPR force public sector workers to fix an exploit they were notified of?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, european-union, any-jurisdiction, security

I live in some EU country and I rely on social security provided by the regional government. There is a website for residents who can sign up and claim benefits without physically visiting an office. While helping a friend sign up, I accidentally discovered critical bugs that could enable anyone visiting the website to run arbitrary code. I documented my findings and sent them via email. I received an automated response that said my email was received but didn't hear any further.

To protect my data I disabled my account and asked all data to be removed from the website. I started walking half an hour to the office and doing everything on paper to receive my benefits. However after months, the exploit seems to have not been fixed yet. I am deeply concerned that a malicious actor could have already accessed the data and made the lives of the most vulnerable of our society even more vulnerable. Since the interface feels more than a decade old which suggests the back-end also is, this is a real possibility. Does GDPR mandate that institutions fix bad code that could compromise security and/or privacy of its users? If not is there any other legislation that I can cite to pressure them to fix their site? If I were outside the EU, what legislation would do the job?

Comment: The word "exploit" is not being using in its plain and non-technical sense in this question. Is there another word which could be used which would be more clear?

Comment: @ohwilleke "security breach" is an approximate equivalent. I am not sure the OP is using the technical jargon correctly anyway - this looks like a _vulnerability_ (the door to the warehouse is left open and unguarded) rather than an _exploit_ (someone went through the open door, took stuff, and ran away). The OP has identified a vulnerability, but they did not use it in a practical manner.

Answer (score 2):

### No, but the organisation can be fined if they don't

Assuming the local government is a data controller, Article 24 [requires](https://www.gdpreu.org/the-regulation/key-concepts/data-controllers-and-processors/#:%7E:text=They%20must%20demonstrate%20fairness%2C%20lawfulness,of%20any%20data%20processing%20activities.) that they:

- Take into account the purpose, nature, context, and scope of any data processing activities.
- Consider the likelihood of any severe risk to the freedoms and rights of any natural persons.
- **Implement appropriate organizational and technical measures and security measures that demonstrate that the data processing activities have been performed in accordance with GDPR regulation.**
- Review and update these measures where necessary.

Having a portal where a potential exploit can expose personal data to a hacker does not satisfy the bolded point.

Feel free to report them to your country's regulator.